# Laravel many to many relationship error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having two `models` under the name of `Plugins` and `User` with tables respectively. I'm trying to have `many to many relationship` with a `pivot table` named `plugin_user` in the `migration` named `create_users_plugins_table.php`.

Following is the schema:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('plugin_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('plugins_id');
        $table->json('contents');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In the `User model` I've following function for relationship:

```
public function userplugins(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Plugins')->withPivot('contents');
}
```

While fetching the row by following code:

```
$user = User::findorFail($id);
return $user->userplugins()->first()->contents;
```

I'm getting an following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'nitsbuilder.plugins_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `plugins`.*, `plugins_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `plugins_user`.`plugins_id` as `pivot_plugins_id`, `plugins_user`.`contents` as `pivot_contents` from `plugins` inner join `plugins_user` on `plugins`.`id` = `plugins_user`.`plugins_id` where `plugins_user`.`user_id` = 1 limit 1)

Please help me out in fixing this bug.

Thanks

Comment: Hope you already run your migrations? And whats the code in your `Plugins` model ?

Comment: Easy as that: plugin_user !== plugins_user the error exactly tells you the problem. You did not define plugins_user but plugin_user - you can change the referenced table name in your relation https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @ArifulHaque I already did that.

Comment: @FrankProvost Thanks for the update. Up from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in your Migration, your table name is

```
`plugin_user`
```

but the query searching for

```
`plugins_user`
```

You might need to update your `Plugin` model with the table name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the name of your table. The error says it was looking for **plugins_user** but your migration shows **plugin_user** table which is missing the s. This might be due to the naming of the model **Plugins** which should be **Plugin**

Either change the table name or go to https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many to check how to change the referenced table of the relation.